# Spanish visa as a prelude to naturalisation

Tags: visa, spain

Filipino (amongst other former Spanish colonies) citizens are entitled to apply for Spanish citizenship after 2 years of residence in Spain. My question is, what is the best visa option for that initial two years of residence? Plus of course any additional advice is welcome.

Answer (score 4):

The full list of visas to enter Spain for longer than 90 days is extensive. You can see an example [here](http://www.vfsglobal.com/spain/mexico/longterm.html).

The issue is that the best visa for you would depend on what your goal is while you are in Spain. For instance, if you are a student or a scientist, there are specific visas you need to ask. If you are going to work for a business in Spain that is going to sponsor you or if you are going to be working on your own. The more flexibility a visa provides, the harder it is to obtain usually.

Good luck!

Comment: (+1) Do you know if all these visas allow you to claim residence? (I am asking because I know at least one other country where years spent under a student visa do not count for the residence requirement prior to naturalization.)

Comment: @GaëlLaurans: I am not positive. I know people that have been able to make it count, but I don't recall what type of student visa they had. It is tricky and, it seems to me, ever changing.